# android landscape dual pane resize

Tags: android, pane

I have an app that is basically a listView which brings up a detail screen when an item is selected.  In landscape I split the screen so that the left had pane contains the listView and the right hand pane contains the detail of the item selected on the left. The dual mode proportions are split 45:55 which is hardcoded in the layout xml.  I want to give the user the ability to change the proportions to their own liking.  Some kind of setting in Preferences would be OK.  Even better would be a "widget" actually on the screen which they could slide to change the proportions.  I haven't found a way of achieving this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: i think you want to use fragment